# Get actual value from other class

Tags: java, swing

How to get actual value from other class?

I've got problem which getting actual value from other class. The value is changing from 0 to 10 every 1 second. Here is how I getting this value to my second Class:

```
komponent_gui.MR(Integer.valueOf(text3.getText()).intValue());
```

And here is my Class to which I want to get value of text3 field:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Komponent extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x;
    private int b;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x,9,30,2);
    }

    public void MR(int a)
    {
        b=a;
    }

    public void on()
    {
        tm.start();
    }

    public void off()
    {
        tm.stop();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        x=b;
        repaint ();
    }
}
```

The problem is that, I've got in this class only first value from text3 field. It isn't refreshing. What is wrong with this class?

Comment: Are you calling `komponent_gui.MR` on each tick?

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please also use more descriptive attribute names.

Comment: NiIsH, yes, on each tick

Comment: @Martyn Please show that code as well

Comment: Tip:  Add @NilsH (the `@`) is important, to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: Five milliseconds (200 Hz) is a rather short period; "0 to 10 every 1 second" sounds more like you want `100` milliseconds (10 Hz).